# Center content in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

i want center content in GridLayout, i use layout_gravity but it still align to left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:columnCount="2" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: just change GridLayout width and height to wrap_content instead of match_parent.

Comment: as you've  set android:columnCount="2" , one textview will always be on the left and one will be next to it,

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I'm assuming you want two columns with the text fields centered in each column, even spacing between the two?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: this make gridlayout center instead of content of gridlayout, when i add element that is span on 2 columns and have width greater then textViews above, textviews alight to left again :(

Comment: in two columns, but only one row have to be bigger and extend to both columns